# Splitting a string into chunks by numeric or alpha character with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split, chunks

I have this:

```
var str = A123B234C456;
```

I need to split it into comma-separated chunks to return something like this:

```
A,123,B,234,c,456
```

I thought a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) would be best for this, but I keep getting stuck. Essentially, I tried to do a string replace, but you cannot use a regular expression in the second argument.

I would love to keep it simple and clean and do something like this, but it does not work:

```
str = str.replace(/[\d]+/, ","+/[\d]+/);
```

But in the real world that would be too simple.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be more sensible to match the characters and then join them:

```
str = str.match(/(\d+|[^\d]+)/g).join(',');
```

But don't omit the quotes when you define the string:

```
var str = 'A123B234C456';
```

Comment: Wow!  Sometimes you just get caught up in over complexity.  That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The string split method can be called with a regular expression.

If the regular expression has a capture group, the separator will be kept in the resulting array.

So here you go:

```
let c = "A123B234C456";
let stringsAndNumbers = c.split(/(\d+)/); // ["A", "123", "B", "234", "C", "456", ""]
```

Since your example ends with numbers, the last element will be empty.
Remove empty array elements:

```
let stringsAndNumbers = c.split(/(\d+)/).filter(el => el != ""); // ["A", "123", "B", "234", "C", "456"]
```

Then join:

```
let stringsAndNumbers = c.split(/(\d+)/).filter(el => el != "").join(","); // "A,123,B,234,C,456"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by replace() using a regular expression.

For example,

```
var str = "A123B234C456";
str = str.replace(/([a-bA-B])/g, '$1,');
```

Now the value of str will be 'A,123,B234,C456'.